# How to run a command in a remote server from Django application using paramiko

Tags: django, ssh, paramiko

From my Django application I have to run a command in a remote server, at a particular folder location, connected using paramiko.

What I have tried:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(my_host, port=my_port, username=my_username', password=my_pass)
client.exec_command("cd path/to/folder; my_command")
```

Any suggestions to achieve it??

Comment: What's the problem with the code you've posted? What went wrong?

Comment: You need to make your question more specific. Also, Paramiko is low level, use fabric instead: http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: When I am executing other commands like git clone and all, its working . But client.exec_command("cd path/to/folder; my_command") is not working.

Comment: ie, I want to change the working directory and execute a command from my Django app, but its not working. But when I have connected to that server from my terminal using ssh and then changed the working directory and executed that command, its working. So its not the problem with that command.

Comment: try allocating a pty first; otherwise you're just executing system commands

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into this problem now...